# Looking for documentation of the `--max-semi-space-size` flag in Node

Tags: node.js

In terms of GC time, this flag seems to come up often, but I'm hoping to get a concise explanation of what this flag does, and how it's affected or should be calculated by other flags (`max-old-space-size`). Is it new, and not documented? Is it old and deprecated in newer versions of Node?